# Datenum behaviour with empty string concatenation

Tags: matlab, date

I've noticed strange behaviour in the function `datenum` with MATLAB R2017a and above:

If you try to run:

```
date = datenum([""],'yyyymmdd');
```

We obtain a warning:

> Warning: Usage of DATENUM with empty date character vectors or empty strings is not supported.
>       Results may change in future versions.

```
date = 
      0x1 empty double column vector
```

But now if we run:

```
date = datenum(["","20181012"],'yyyymmdd')
```

We obtain:

```
date = 2x1:
          737426 % which corresponds to 20190101
          737345
```

So both times we give an empty string to `datenum`, but if the array contains multiple strings, the result is different. Why can an empty string be parsed when other strings are present, even another empty string, but not when on its own?

Comment: `datenum(["",""],'yyyymmdd')` is even funnier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a bug.

The beginning of the `datenum` function contains

> ```
> arg1 = stringToLegacyText(arg1);
> ```

where `arg1` is the first input of `datenum`. The `stringToLegacyText` function does the following, according to its code:

> ```
> S = STRINGTOLEGACYTEXT(S) converts the string array S to a char row vector,
> if S is a scalar, or to a cellstr, if S is not a scalar.
> ```

That is,

```
>> stringToLegacyText([""])
ans =
  0×0 empty char array

>> stringToLegacyText(["" ""])
ans =
  1×2 cell array
    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}

>> stringToLegacyText(["" "20181012"])
ans =
  1×2 cell array
    {0×0 char}    {'20181012'}
```

Later on there is this test:

> ```
> if isdatestr && isempty(arg1)
>    n = zeros(0,1);
>    warning(message('MATLAB:datenum:EmptyDate'));
>    return;
> end
> ```

which produces the warning you mention if `arg1` is empty. The test yields true for the first case above (`[""]`), but not for the second (`["" ""]`) or third (`["" "20181012"]`). So for the second or third cases the function continues to

> ```
> n = dtstr2dtnummx(arg1,matlab.internal.datetime.cnv2icudf(arg2))
> ```

The `dtstr2dtnummx` function is undocumented:

> ```
> >> which dtstr2dtnummx
> built-in (undocumented)
> ```

But it expects a cell array of char vectors as first argument, and somehow gives `737426` for empty char vectors:

```
>> dtstr2dtnummx({''}, matlab.internal.datetime.cnv2icudf(arg2))
ans =
      737426

>> dtstr2dtnummx({'' ''}, matlab.internal.datetime.cnv2icudf(arg2))
ans =
      737426
      737426

>> dtstr2dtnummx({'' '20181012'}, matlab.internal.datetime.cnv2icudf(arg2))
ans =
      737426
      737345
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to look at how [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) parses its input arguments in R2018a by typing `edit datenum`. One of the first things it does is pass the first argument to a function `stringToLegacyText`, which converts it from a [string type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) to either a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html) or (and this is key) a [cell array of character arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html):

```
>> import matlab.internal.datatypes.stringToLegacyText  % Get helper function
>> stringToLegacyText([""])  % Single empty string

ans =

  0×0 empty char array

>> stringToLegacyText(["", "20181012"])  % Array of strings

ans =

  1×2 cell array

    {0×0 char}    {'20181012'}
```

A short while later in the code, it performs this check:

```
if isdatestr && isempty(arg1)
    n = zeros(0,1);
    warning(message('MATLAB:datenum:EmptyDate'));
    return;
end
```

And this is where the discrepancy arises. The [`isempty`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) function returns `true` for an empty character array (issuing the warning) but returns false for a non-empty cell array, even if that cell array contains all empty objects. For whatever reason, the empty entries default to January 1<sup>st</sup>, 2019:

```
>> datestr(737426)

ans =

    '01-Jan-2019'
```

I think the correct fix here would be to update the condition to check for a cell array with any empty entries:

```
if isdatestr && (isempty(arg1) || (iscell(arg1) && any(cellfun('isempty', arg1))))
    n = zeros(0,1);
    warning(message('MATLAB:datenum:EmptyDate'));
    return;
end
```